# What's the technical limit to how small RFID-like system antenna can be?

Tags: power, wireless, rfid, antenna, inductive

So far I haven't seen a contactless smart card smaller than a standard credit card. My "biometric" travel passport holds a chip powered off the antenna - I lit the plastic holding the chip through with a bright LED flashlight and the antenna occupies more or less the dimensions of a credit card as well.

Now I understand that the antenna must be "large enough" to serve for inductive energy transfer, but what's the lower limit to how small it can be?

Comment: As Steven says - size CAN be small. Area will control maximum energy that can be collected from available field. If you are powering a receiver with the collected energy and/or wish to transfer data from them then more size will increase available energy and range. (You can always make a large one that works poorly, but there will be upper limits to how well you can make one of a given size work).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RFID tags can be made Damn Small™. Among the smaller ones are **subdermal tags** used for instance in animal identification:

[image]

IIRC in Belgium every horse must have such a subdermal RFID tag.
Other small tags (smaller than a credit card, anyway) are key fob sized tags

[image]

and, about the same size, RFID tags that look like a wrist watch, I often see those in, again Belgian, cafés and restaurants to identify the waiter at the cash register computer.

RFID most often uses 125kHz or 13.5MHz carriers. If you go to 2.4GHz you can further miniaturize the tag. The following, 0.4mm x 0.4mm in size, is the smallest I could find:

[image]

So RFID tags can be made very small indeed. I guess there are much less miniaturization possibilities for the transmitter if it wants to extend the near field to a workable distance. The tag has to be in the near field to be detectable.

Comment: Wow, I was going to say grain of rice, but apparently, it's down to a few grains of sand.  Impressive.

Comment: Can you reference the images, especially the last? They're interesting.

Comment: @tyblu - I had to look them up again, I don't keep links to everything I find. http://images.google.com works well, you can spot an image immediately, instead of having to click link after link. Anyway, the last one is probably from [this blog](http://freepeopleontheland.wordpress.com/2009/09/17/alert-dont-vax-me-bro/). The top one may be from [here](http://peopleforfreedom.com/new-world-order-news/rogue-government/obama-hellcare-microchips-americans/)